# Two 'boxes' under one another and another on the right

Tags: html, css

[please click for updated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqPAU.png)Currently, my webpage looks like this:

[image]

But I want the bottom box to fit right under the top one while keeping the box on the right in the same place.

This is what i have now

```
#intro-chemistry{
    background-color: #C7C7C7;
    border-top: 7px solid rgb(177, 177, 177);
    width: 242px;
    height: 103px;
    padding: 13.75px;
    margin: 13.75px 13.75px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}

#intro-physics{
    background-color: #C7C7C7;
    border-top: 7px solid rgb(177, 177, 177);
    width: 238px;
    height: 285px;
    padding: 13.75px;
    margin: 13.75px 13.75px;
    text-align: 10, 10, 10, 10;
    float: left;
}

#intro-classic{
    background-color: #C7C7C7;
    border-top: 7px solid rgb(177, 177, 177);
    width: 242px;
    height: 103px;
    padding: 13.75px;
    margin: 13.75px 13.75px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
```

I'm trying to get the box "classic" to fit right under the box "chemistry' whilst the box 'physics' stays put.

Comment: Put both ''chemistry' and 'classic' in a div and give float left.

Comment: IT WOULD APPEAR THAT YOUR CAPS LOCK KEY GOT STUCK. PLEASE USE THE "EDIT" LINK TO FIX THAT.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your HTML structure.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-left">
  <div id="intro-chemistry">
    Chemistry
  </div>
  <div id="intro-classic">
    Classic
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-right">
  <div id="intro-physics">
    Physics 
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-left{
  float: left;
  width: 242px;
}
.col-right{
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: this only seems to push it further to the right whilst the one below stays underneath the one on the right

Comment: I also have a column to the right which might be why its not working, i've edited the top post with a picture of it overall, under - "please click for updated image"

Comment: I have updated the code. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gph4w93k/

Comment: unfortuantely still having same issue :( :(

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/clairellend/n5b4vv8o/1/ this is of the whole thing now that i've taken out the structure you made and what it looks like. the 'bike classic' box is sitting on top of the two below it and just needs to be somehow pushed up

Comment: Your html code is so messed up. Some of the tags are not even closed.

Comment: yes its my first time coding, thankyou. hence why i'm on here for help.

Comment: StackOverflow is for answering specific technical questions on a well formed problem, so that others can benefit from understanding the answer. It's not a general tutorial site or a way of getting others' opinions on how to do something. Thanks! :)

Comment: cheers bud :) :) :) :)